# Rails—removing uuid references (migration)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I want to delete a table in the db and all it's references in other tables.

I've seen someone suggest this:

```
remove_reference :hiring_questions, :group
```

But my reference is a `uuid`:

```
t.uuid :group_id, index: true
```

Will the `remove_references` command work on this? If not, what will?